# Xuggle build failed on ubuntu x64?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, ubuntu-11.10, xuggle, xuggler

After downloading the source code from [GIT hub](https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler) I setup the enviroment variables
as [Xuggle YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuC_RKLotLE) said so

```
   export XUGGLE_HOME=/usr/local
   export PATH=$XUGGLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$XUGGLE_HOME
```

Then I simply started the ant test by command

```
ant run-tests
```

Which gave me following output with error in the end ..

```
compile-native-do:
     [exec] Making all in captive
     [exec] make[1]: Entering directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive'
     [exec] Making all in libvo-aacenc
     [exec] make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libvo-aacenc'
     [exec] Incarcerated package configured: ../../../../../captive/libvo-aacenc
     [exec] Incarcerating package ../../../../../captive/libvo-aacenc to fake DESTDIR=/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive
     [exec] make[3]: Entering directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libvo-aacenc/csrc'
     [exec] make  all-am
     [exec] make[4]: Entering directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libvo-aacenc/csrc'
     [exec] make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libvo-aacenc/csrc'
     [exec] make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libvo-aacenc/csrc'
     [exec] Incarceration complete: ../../../../../captive/libvo-aacenc
     [exec] make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libvo-aacenc'
     [exec] Making all in libopencore-amr
     [exec] make[2]: Entering directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libopencore-amr'
     [exec] Incarcerated package must be reconfigured; regenerating out of date captive Makefile from: ../../../../../captive/libopencore-amr/csrc/configure
     [exec] /bin/mkdir -p csrc
     [exec] cd csrc && sh ../incarcerate
     [exec] Creating release version of libopencore-amr: 
     [exec] Copying /home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/../../../../captive/libopencore-amr/csrc to /home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libopencore-amr/csrc
     [exec] Configuring libopencore-amr with these options:  --enable-shared
     [exec] checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
     [exec] checking whether build environment is sane... yes
     [exec] checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
     [exec] checking for gawk... no
     [exec] checking for mawk... mawk
     [exec] checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
     [exec] checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
     [exec] checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
     [exec] checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     [exec] checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     [exec] checking for g++... no
     [exec] checking for c++... no
     [exec] checking for gpp... no
     [exec] checking for aCC... no
     [exec] checking for CC... no
     [exec] checking for cxx... no
     [exec] checking for cc++... no
     [exec] checking for cl.exe... no
     [exec] checking for FCC... no
     [exec] checking for KCC... no
     [exec] checking for RCC... no
     [exec] checking for xlC_r... no
     [exec] checking for xlC... no
     [exec] configure: error: in `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libopencore-amr/csrc':
     [exec] configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
     [exec] See `config.log' for more details.
     [exec] make[2]: *** [/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libopencore-amr/csrc/Makefile] Error 1
     [exec] make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
     [exec] make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
     [exec] checking for C++ compiler default output file name... 
     [exec] Could not configure library: "/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/../../../../captive/libopencore-amr"; you may want to try disabling it or installing your own version
     [exec] make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/libopencore-amr'
     [exec] make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/uroot/xuggle/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive'

BUILD FAILED
/home/uroot/xuggle/mk/buildtools/buildhelper.xml:1149: exec returned: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have gcc/g++ installed:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try disabling it in:
Users/siva/Downloads/xuggle-xuggle-xuggler-dbd82d2/mk/buildtools/buildhelper.xml:1149:

line 1149 should be set to false